Optimization error in quantum dot graphene doping with antimony atoms
%chk=/home/surface/Desktop/abbasi/sb/sb/new.chk
%nprocshared=31
%mem=30GB
# opt b3lyp/6-31g(d) geom=connectivity extrabasis
.
.
.
.
H C 0
6-31g(d)
****
Sb 0
lanl2dz
****

Sb 0
lanl2dz

And I encountered this error, does anyone know what I should do?
Error termination via Lnk1e in /home/surface/Desktop/g16/l502.exe


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
